# Setup proxy configuration for ibm websphere server in console

Tags: http, proxy, websphere, setting

My WebSphere ESB server runs behind corporate proxy server in our network.
When I try to access external web-service i get network exceptions (cannot access destination host).

Is there any way to set my proxy configuration in console, except server startup params?
-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800

Comment: I'd already be grateful if I'd find the proper place where I could place the startup params - there are a myriad of different batch files that have no common environment variable which could be used for that...

Comment: See if this helps

Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections

Give your proxy configuration there and let me know the error if any

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @rabs Not really. I ended up with startup params...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
Since WAS leverage JVM TCP/IP capabilities, the only way is what you found: configure the JVM through the VM Args.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Those particular options can be set as Additional Properties to the JVM

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_configwbsclient2webproxy.html

In WAS, options to the JVM are set in Application servers > *server_name* > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365